# How to get a list's new Name after changing it with the REST API on SPO?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

On SPO, after changing a list's Name in 'List Settings' > 'List name, description and navigation', the list's Name in the SPO webpages gets immediately updated, but the `GET /_api/Web/Lists(guid'my-guid')` endpoint still returns the old Name in its `Title` property.

How do I get the updated Name (ex: I'm looking at the wrong property), or is it simply impossible with the REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking at wrong `Title` property.

I replicated the scenario at my end, I changed my list name from `Contoso` to `Contoso 1`.

And hit the REST API and it returned the updated name.

[image]

It does not need any additional time to update the details.

So, try again and try to look all the `Title` property in your JSON result.

You can try hitting the REST endpoint in the browser directly.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer! Sending the request in the browser does return the updated Title, however the API still returns the old title if I use cURL. Guess I'll need to check if there's issues with my cURL parameters, credentials, or if there's any caching going in.

Comment: After checking, it seems like the API returns different values when using the browser cookies and an access token from AAD. Question asked here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254417/